# Navision 2015 get record after insert with page web service

Tags: ssis, navision, kingswaysoft

I am using SOAP web service to insert the record into Navision with KingswaySoft SSIS component.

One thing is realy bugging me.

The KingswaySoft destination NAV component returns Key and IsNew values.

I try to use the Key to retrieve the inserted record.

I am using the filter on a NAV source component:

```
<filter>
<Field>Key</Field><Criteria>32;uhMAAAJ7/1MAVABJAEsANgA0ADQAMQ==9;3083718490;</Criteria>
</filter>
```

This actualy returns a lot of records (9K+), I of course expected exactly 1 or 0 if not found.

What am I doing wrong? How can I retrieve the record I just inserted into NAV? I need to read the generated "No" field from NAV.

How do you then retrieve inserted record data?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is how Dynamics NAV query designed. You can filter on almost any other columns, but just not the Key column, based on our experimentation. The Key column is a special one in Dynamics NAV system.

In our most recent release (SSIS Integration Toolkit v3.1 for Microsoft Dynamics NAV which was released on Jan 22, 2016), we added the capability to return the No field as the additional identifier of the record, which you can use for logging or any other purposes applicable.

Hope this helps.